# does skip ci work with build validation pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a branch policy for build validation.  As a final step i am wanting to update a file in the pull request and push it into the branch.  it doesn't appear that [skip ci] works for these build triggers.  is there another way to accomplish this quality gate?

deeper part of scenario.  pull request is building a docker image, and tagging with git hash.  i'm updating a yaml file with the new tag so i only have to build the image once.  at some point i want to set up another pipeline that will deploy this image based off a successful run of this pipeline(build validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does skip ci work with build validation pipelines?

The answer is No.

First, I need to indicate that this is two different scenarios. As we know, the `[skip ci]` or `[ci skip]` is used to **skip running CI**, like the option 
**Enable continuous integration** on UI:

[image]

However, our current scenario is **branch policy for build validation** instead of CI. This is very different from CI, although they seem to be doing the same build task. Branch policy is to protect our branches from being corrupted by incorrect submit. This is a verified operation instead of continuous integration.

Check the document [Skipping CI for individual commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-commits) for some more details.

So, this is two different scenarios, we could not apply the CI settings to the branch policy.

Second, just like I said in the first point, Branch policy is used to protect our branches, any commit requires validation by branch pliocy, although sometimes we can know that our modifications don't require build validation, but we're not sure if there are any where we overlook that cause our target branch to be broken. Skip unnecessary verification will bring us some construction convenience, but with the risk measurement it brings, these conveniences are negligible, so we don't recommend skipping the verification of the branch office strategy.

Hope this helps.